# CakePHP 1.2 Number Helper - Currency method format to GDP £

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

How Do I format this code to display a Great British Pound Currency (£) sign but only next to the $item['total']?

```
<?php echo $id; ?>Total"><?php echo $number->currency (isset($item['total']) ? 
$item['total'] : $item['quantity'] * $item['price']); ?>
```

I can't seem to get the syntax right.

This attempt did not work:

```
<?php echo $id; ?>Total"><?php echo $number->currency (isset($item['total'], 'GDP') ? 
$item['total'] : $item['quantity'] * $item['price']); ?>
```

The documentation is here:
http://api12.cakephp.org/class/number-helper#method-NumberHelpercurrency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php echo $number->currency ((isset($item['total']) ? $item['total'] : $item['quantity'] * $item['price']),'GBP'); ?>
```

Hope this helps